# Div container to go to edges of page

Tags: css

On my wordpress [Website Homepage](http://www.institute101.com) I inserted a horizontal grey strip containing social network links. I want this to touch the edges of the page over-flowing out of the body, how can I achieve this?

This is the code I used;

```
.outer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.outer` rule isn't the one you'll need to adjust. Looking in the 'styles.css' document find the rule that you've written for `.socialstrip`. (change the `.` to a `#`)

```
    #socialstrip {
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
    }
```

You won't need to do anything else because the class `.outer` that's applied to it already gives you a width of 100%. Be aware that when you give this element a position of 'absolute' the element below it will not recognize that the `#socialstrip` element is above it. It will appear to lay over top of it. To fix this just add more margin to the top of the `.bottomstrip` element. Like this:

```
.bottomstrip{
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

That should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer is very clear and works! Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: This may be caused by the browser but when I zoom in to 125% or 150% the socialstrip detaches from the right side of the page, same goes for the footer. Is there a way to fix that? right:0?